# Integer arguments is different, but when compared, the results still says objects are equal? where did I go wrong?

Tags: java, generics

Im have only recently started coding so please forgive me for asking simple silly questions like this. but i cant find out what is wrong with this code. when i enter different Integer arguments for different variables, and compare the objects, the result is true, eventhough it is obviously not. can someone help me out with it? thanks in advance!!

```
public class CompareObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComparePair<Integer, String> cp1 = new ComparePair<>(4, "size");
        ComparePair<Integer, String> cp2 = new ComparePair<>(3784, "size");
        boolean same = CompareObjects.compare(cp1, cp2);
        System.out.println(same);
    }

    public static <T, S> boolean compare(ComparePair<T, S> p1p, ComparePair<T, S> p2p) {
        return p2p.getT().equals(p2p.getT())
                && p1p.getS().equals(p2p.getS());
    }

}

class ComparePair<T, S> {

    private T tField;
    private S sField;

    public ComparePair(T tParameter, S sParameter) {
        tField = tParameter;
        sField = sParameter;
    }

    public void setT(T tParameter) {
        tField = tParameter;
    }

    public void setS(S sParameter) {
        sField = sParameter;
    }

    public T getT() {
        return tField;
    }

    public S getS() {
        return sField;
    }
}
```

Comment: Double check that you're not trying to compare `p2p` to itself anywhere.  I see a typo.  To prevent scenarios like this, use more meaningful variable names, such as `left` and `right`, `firstObject` and `secondObject`.

Comment: here you made a mistake `p2p.getT().equals(p2p.getT())`

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Im new to programming so everything seems so difficult for me. Sorry have to bother you with such a silly mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return p2p.getT().equals(p2p.getT())
            && p1p.getS().equals(p2p.getS());
```

You compare getT to itself as they are both on p2p.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Im sorry that i have to bother you for such a silly mistake.

Comment: @Jess If it solved the problem then accept the answer by clicking on the tick :) No thanks are needed. As a note for the future though this is a great example of why meaningful and different variable names are a good idea - your mistake would be much more obvious if the names were more different.